# Различное отображение rgba у border-color и backgroud

Tags: css

Устанавливаю одно и то же значение `rgba(0,0,0,.1)` для `border-color` и `background`. Получается так, что граница немного темнее фона.
Почему так происходит, и можно ли это как-нибудь отключить?

Пример на `input`'e:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 9px;
    height: 28px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Мне надо, чтобы обводка была темнее, поэтому сделал их одинаковыми. Везде ли так будет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так происходит, потому-что фон "заползает" под border.

И видно этот эффект, потому-что цвет бордера у вас с прозрачностью, происходит накладывание цветов, поэтому бордер становится чуть темнее.

Это стандартное поведение, если вам необходимо его изменить, то почитайте про свойство `background-clip` : http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-clip

Comment: Спасибо! :) Все понял, обводка идет внутри, а не снаружи. Меня такое поведение устраивает :)

Answer (score 1):

фоновый цвет для input черный с 10% прозрачностью к нему добавляется border тоже на 10% и получается 20% то есть rgba(0,0,0,.2);